# What is the state vector x(t) in the cost function - LQR

Tags: optimization, control-theory, simulation, optimal-control, kalman-filter

The cost function for LQR optimization is:

$$J_{min} = \int_{0}^{ \infty} (x^T (t) Q x (t)+ u^T (t) R u(t))dt $$

But what is $x (t)$ ?

1. The solution for the open simulation? $ x(t)  = e^{At} x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^\tau e^{At}B dt$
2. The trajectories for the state feedback simulation?

Example:
I have created a matrix $Q$ and a matrix $R$ that gives me good state feedback in the simulation. And through the simulation I have got the trajectories $x(t)$. I allready know $u(t)$ because it's a step function.

Now the next step is to optimize $R$ and $Q$ to minimize $J_{min}$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x(t)$ are states evolving along $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$. The optimal solution $u(t)$ minimizing the integral is a linear state-feedback $u(t) = -Lx(t)$, so your statement that $u(t)$ is a step does not make any sense, nor does the idea that you want to optimize $R$ and $Q$. You first pick $Q$ and $R$ based on your desired performance and compromise between control effort and state convergence, and then you compute the optimal feedback $L$ by solving an algebraic Riccati equation.

Comment: Hej Johan! So how do I optimize so $J_{min}$ will be small as possible?

Comment: You solve the Riccati equation, L = lqr(A,B,Q,R) in matlab. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator

Comment: But that's not minimize the cost function. That's only guessing.

Comment: How do you mean guess? The optimal input $u(t)$ is a linear time-invariant state feedback, computed from a Riccati equation. That's a fundamental result in modern (50-60s...) control theory.

Comment: But how can I tell if I have best $R$ and $Q$ matrices?

Comment: There are no best $Q$ and $R$. They are your tuning knobs to achieve a desirable closed-loop response

Comment: Okey. So if I got a good state feedback by tuning $R$ and $Q$, I can say that $J_{min}$ is small?

Comment: It does not make sense to talk about it being small, as you always can scale $Q$ and $R$ with an arbitrarily small value, making the cost arbitrarily close to zero, while still leading to the same optimal control input. The relevant fact is that for given $Q$ and $R$, the integral is minimized by $u = -Lx$ where $L$ is the LQ state feedback matrix.

Comment: Ok. I other words. I can ignore the cost function and only focus on tuning $Q$ and $R$ before I use the Riccati equation to find my control law $L$ ?

Comment: You are not ignoring it, you're simply applying the fact that the optimal controller for that cost function is computed using the algebraic Riccati equation. In the end of the day though, it is only a structured way to derive a linear state-feedback with known robustness properties etc, with intuitive tuning via $Q$ and $R$.

Comment: So insted of using the integral cost function, I use the ARE "cost function"?

Comment: You never explicitly work with the integral, as you know the solution is given by the ARE

Comment: If I never going to work with the integral. Why are Ljung/Glad/Lennartsson etc teaching that cost integral then? It's seems like waste of time.

Comment: The ARE, and $Q$ and $R$, would be a complete mystery if you didn't know about the the cost function defined by the integral.

Comment: So how should I define the ARE? A tool for solving the integral? Edit: I know the equation.

Comment: The ARE is the way the optimal control problem is solved.

Comment: Yes. I have built a lot of LQG's with integral action. But I would not call LQR/LQG optimal control (even if it's named Optimal Control) if the user only tuning $Q$ and $R$ wihout any calculations of which $Q$ and $R$ are the best. That's the reason why I'm critical to the integral why it's never used.

Comment: LQR is the most basic and classical result from optimal control theory. The fact that you use the objective function, i.e. $Q$ and $R$ as handles to achieve a particular performance is another issue, but that is something you do in essentially all optimization problems, including optimal control (you select the objective to achieve a roughly suitable behavior, and then minimize that objective).

Comment: Do you know how to optimize an LQR? Do it require dynamic programming?

Comment: No, you solve the ARE. L = lqr(A,B,Q,R) in matlab.

Comment: Ok. And that will give me optimal controlling for the dynamic specific behaviour in the simulation? Exampel: If I choose $Q$ and $R$ to the identity matrix. I will get a dynamic specific behaviour. Is that behaviour optimal? Perfect amout of energy due to the state feedback?

Comment: it will give you the feedback that minimizes the integral where you weight all states and inputs equally. What is optimal behavior? Which is the optimal car, the fastest car or the car that uses the least fuel? You define the compromise through $Q$ and $R$.

Comment: ...and the integral gets even smaller if I choose a better $Q$ and $R$? That's the goal?

Comment: No. You can trivially get the integral to be 0 by using $Q=R=0$. You want to get nice closed-loop behavior and control usage, and to do that, you select $Q$ and $R$ suitably, as we now that LQ controllers have very good robustness properties etc.

Comment: Ok. Now I have got all my questions answerd. Thank you. Yes, I know that LQR has very good robustness properties, unlike LQG which has no guaranteed stability margins. I have a question for that on my page. If a LQI has guaranteed stability margins.